# How to perform a linear combination between 2 numpy arrays that approximates a 3rd array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, approximation

On paper it seems quite simple so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I've got 2 input arrays X1 and X2 of the same shape, and a target array Y also of the same shape. I'd like to combine X1 and X2 in some way to produce an approximation of Y. The combination should be element-wise, eg X1[0][0] combines with X2[0][0] and so on. I'd appreciate any ideas on how to do this in python, and if you think there are good non-linear methods that would also be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: please provide a minimal example (X1, X2 and Y) for clarity

Comment: a linear combination is defined as `ax + by` so the problem is to find the coefficients a and b such that `ax + by = z`. This to me seems more of a mathematics problem than a python one.

Comment: @mozway Just standard float arrays. So all could be something like np.array([0.3, 0.4, 1.2, 1.4], [2.3, 0.5, 1.8, 0.1])

Comment: @Fra93 Well yeah but I'm wondering if there are convenient python solutions, eg the numpy polyfit method does a linear approximation with 1 input array and a target array

Comment: @Mike then I think you first should come up with an  algorithm and then try implement it. If you fail, you ask here. If you don't have any algorithm in mind, you should ask on mathematics stack exchange, or maybe the dsp stack exchange :)